# Redirect folder/page.php to folder/page .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I'm looking for help with .htaccess file.
I would like to do `domain.net/test` for `domain.net/test.php` and also `domain.net/folder` for `domain.net/folder/index.php`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in site root .htccess:

```
DirectorySlash On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```